# Typescript: 2 > 100 == true

Tags: javascript, typescript

I ran into a strange problem when coding in typescript. Somehow 2 > 100 == true (?).

and I cant really figure it out...

Here is my code:

```
if (!this.multipleYAxis) {
    for (let d of this.getDatasources()) {
        let options = this.getGraphTypeOption(d.id);
        console.log(this.yMax + ' < ' + options.max);
        console.log(this.yMax < options.max);
        if (this.yMax < options.max)
            this.yMax = options.max;

        if (this.yMin > options.min)
            this.yMin = options.min;
    }

    if (this.getChart().yAxis[1] != undefined) {
        this.getChart().yAxis[1].update({
        max: this.yMax
    });

    this.getChart().yAxis[1].update({
            min: this.yMin
        });
    }
}
```

yMin and yMax is declare like this:

```
private yMin: number = 0;
private yMax: number = 0;
```

options is declared like this:

```
export interface GraphTypeOption {
    ...
    max: number;
    min: number;
    ...
}
```

The code im currently testing is running 2 datasources. So the for loop will run twice.

This is my output:

```
100 < 100
false
100 < 2
true
```

The only way in the chrome developer tool console I can get 100 < 2 to true is typing in "100" < "2" but as you can see in my declaration `this.yMax` and `options.max` is clearly a type of int/number. The compiler doesn't even like that I want to explicity cast them to int because the cast function require variables of type string.

Anyone knows what causing this trouble? Is it the typescript->javascript that mess it up?

Comment: I'm sure you're comparing strings.

Comment: `console.log(this.yMax, ' < ', options.max);` and that will prove that at least one of these is a string

Comment: Do you have any compiling warnings? How about logging `typeof this.yMax`?

Comment: Logging? Why logging? Use the debugger.

Comment: @MaxArt I just did a typeof on both and they're strings.

Comment: So what do you all suggest I should be doing instead? Declare them in typescript as strings and then explicit cast them to int in the if? I've been doing this several months now and this is the first time I've ran into a case like this.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho: It depends where they come from. If you're getting them from an HTML `input` element's `value`, for instance, then yes, because by definition that's a string, not a number. But where you fix this depends entirely on where the values come from.

Comment: @T.J Crowder ok thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> as you can see in my declaration this.yMax and options.max is clearly a type of int/number

And yet, if you're seeing `100 < 2` as `true`, then you're comparing strings, despite the type annotations. Using your debugger, inspect the value of the things you're comparing. You'll find that they're `"100"` and `"2"`, not `100` and `2`. From that, you can then find what the root cause of them being strings is.

Gratuitous example:

```js
console.log("100" < "2"); // true
console.log(100 < 2);     // false
```

Comment: Even if its a string like you all suggest and I suspects. How come in typescript I declare them as a number but the outcome is a string anyways?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho: TypeScript's type annotations disappear when you compile. Apparently, at some stage, you're getting something that's a string that TypeScript was promised would be a number, but isn't.

Comment: What do you suggest I should be doing instead to get this to work? I'll always done this way and this is the first time I've had this problem.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho: I made my suggestion in the answer: Use your debugger to examine the contents of those variables at runtime. You'll find that they're strings. So then you trace where they came from to find out why you're getting strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Yes but what do you suggest how I should write it in typescript. To get javascript to handle them as int? Declare them as a string and then explicit cast them to int?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho: Sorry, overlapping comments, I commented on the question replying to that query there.

Comment: Use type coercion to convert the strings to numbers: `+this.yMax < +options.max`

Comment: @Martin: That puts a bandaid on the problem; the *solution* is to avoid getting cut in the first place.

Comment: I changed the value that was comming from the server of type string to int and now its working. Thanks!